# LookUP Value returning multiple concatenated values

Tags: microsoft-excel, array, worksheet-function

I have two columns, one is a 'Category' with a simple code and the other column named 'Tree/group qualities' with one, or many of the following categories that are, if multiple, concatenated using comma, see example

[image]

I need this column L

[image]

to fill in a value made of the category code (A,B,C or U) and a number/multiple numbers (1 to 3) that depend on this

[image]

So, for example in the first image, the first row with data would be translated into my column L ('CAT') as "B,2,3,1"

I've tried using =VLOOKUP but can only get the first match. I think creating and Array could be the solution but I think I need some advice on this.

Comment: You may be able to use COUNTIF in Excel to count the number of rows which contain each value. How many rows are we talking about and how often do you have to do this? Could just use text filters for each "contains" value for a quick summation, or maybe even a Pivot Table.

Comment: I get raw data like this that need individual analysis but there are no more combinations than Categories (A to U) and no more 'qualities' than the shown in the pictures. There are dozens of tabs with other many calculations happening at the same time so I need this to happen automatically and populating a concatenated column

Comment: Are you familiar with Python? I think that would be an easier method to automate.

Comment: I am not unfortunately, plus I am trying to bound every calculation happening in the spreadsheet with plain Excel formulas and VBA

Comment: Have you tried the Super User StackExchange forum, per this?  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155487/if-i-had-a-question-with-excel-which-site-would-i-use

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround. not very efficient or clever but it does work.

Basically, I created an array with all the possibles combinations of the three elements and added another column with the right code that should have been retrieved. 
[image]

By using the formula below, you can now make Excel ready every single value and finding its code in the column based on a macth

=IF(Trees!AC2<>"",VLOOKUP(Trees!AC2,QUALITIES_ARRAY,2,FALSE),"")

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I have a working solution. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to enter Visual Basic Editor, create a new module and paste this code into it. You will be able to use the `CAT` function in any cell like this: `=CAT(category,qualities)`.

```vb
' Function that expects a quality and returns the respective code
' Important: Tick check box beside "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" in Tools > References
Function lookup_code(ByRef quality)
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    dict.Add "Arboricultural", "1"
    dict.Add "Landscape", "2"
    dict.Add "Cultural_and_Conservation", "3"
    lookup_code = dict(quality)
End Function

' Function to output the concatenated CAT code
' Use in any Excel cell as `=CAT(category, qualities)`
' Expects a category (e.g. "A") and a string of one or more qualities, separated by a comma
Function CAT(category, qualities)
    Dim code As String
    If InStr(qualities, ",") > 0 Then ' Check for commas
        Dim QualityArray() As String
        QualityArray = Split(qualities, ",") ' Split string at commas
        For Each q In QualityArray
            code = code & "," & lookup_code(q) ' match code to quality
        Next
    Else
        code = "," & lookup_code(CStr(qualities))
    End If
    CAT = category & code ' return category and codes (e.g. "B,2,3,1")
End Function
```